# JQuery onChange event triggering an infinite amount of times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form in which I'm trying to pull data from the database to calculate and show the price dynamically on the screen. I can pull correctly the data using JQuery and Ajax with select fields, but the issue comes when I change the value in the number input fields (width and height), the value is saved correctly in the variable but it makes the onchange event trigger infinitely until it crashes. How can I avoid that infinite trigger?

This is part of my html (blade, since I'm using Laravel)

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" id="curtainForm">
    <h4>Producto</h4>
    <h6>Modelo</h6>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control " name="model_id" id="model_id">
                <option value="">Selecciona el modelo</option>
                <option value="1">Model</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <h6>Cubierta</h6>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control" name="cover_id" id="cover_id" >
                <option value="">Selecciona la cubierta</option>
                <option value="1">Cover</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <h6>Datos</h6>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.1" id="width">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.1" id="height">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my Jquery script:

```
    <script>
        $('#curtainForm').change(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var model_id = $(this).find('#model_id').val();
            var cover_id = $(this).find('#cover_id').val();
            var width = $(this).find('#width').val();
            var height = $(this).find('#height').val();
            console.log(model_id);
            console.log(cover_id);
            console.log(width);
            console.log(height);
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you putting a change event listener on a div with all kinds of elements in it? When the ajax runs and inserts html, it changes the div which triggers the ajax and over and over. have somethign else like a specific user interaction trigger the event change

Comment: @Kinglish `change` event is not fired by a div, it fires only by form control elements when the value of an element is changed by a user (programmatical changes don't fire the said event).

Comment: I didn't add the full blade file since it has more stuff not related to the jquery. The ajax writes in a different div in a second column. The function works well with just the selects but it loops on the number inputs. The idea is that once the user changes the data in the form, the other div will be updated with data from the database. I could change it to an on click and add a button but that wouldn't be ideal

Comment: @PatoFb Could you add a [mcve], without the server-side mess.

Comment: @Teemu I think that should do it

Comment: Nope, [the code doesn't crash](https://jsfiddle.net/kdcbp1so/). Again, we need [mre], we can't fix a bug which doesn't exist.

Comment: I am using a template for the front end which already had some scripts, deleted some and found out the error came from one of those (no idea why). Thank you for your time and sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script -

```
<script >
$('#curtainForm').find('select, input').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $wrapper = $('#curtainForm'),
        model_id = $wrapper.find('#model_id').val(),
        cover_id = $wrapper.find('#cover_id').val(),
        width = $wrapper.find('#width').val(),
        height = $wrapper.find('#height').val(),
        _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
        
    console.log('Model: ' + model_id);
    console.log('Cover: ' + cover_id);
    console.log('Width: ' + width);
    console.log('Height: ' + height);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried it, still triggers until it crashes

Comment: Then there must be some other scripts on the page retriggering the change event. My script is working fine. You can test it here - https://jsfiddle.net/virtueplanet/vocd1wy6/10/